# java binding with a free c function: how to correctly free an object

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-native-interface, jna, finalize

Ok, there is a C method called on a pointer which frees the memory area.
I don't want my java binding user to explicitely call this method, because in java it makes no sense and this is a basically a data structure.

So, I just made a finalize() override putting there the c call.
Anyway people say it is not good to rely on finalize...do you have any better idea?

Comment: A finalizer is indeed the best option you can come up with; however, do not forget to call `super.finalize()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with using the `finalize` method: you have no guarantee of when or if it will be called, it forces the garbage collector to do extra work, it's easy to get it wrong.

It is very common need to free resources, whether they are open file descriptors, window handles, database result sets, or something else. In these cases the classes have explicit `close` and `dispose` methods, which the user must call. I would suggest you follow the example set by these classes and add a `close` method. If you implement the `AutoCloseable` interface the API user will even be able to use the try-with-resources statement, and not have to call `close()` explicitly.

An alternative  that's sometimes possible is creating a direct ByteBuffer and passing it to the C library, instead of the C library allocating memory on its own. The off-heap buffer is then freed when the ByteBuffer object is garbage collected. Incidentally, this is implemented using  phantom references  from the [`java.lang.ref` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html).